# Using map/filter behavior on Map instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I have this Express route:

```
app.use('/stop_jobs', function (req, res, next) {

  const jobId = req.query && req.query.job_id;

  const stopped : Array<any> = [];

  for (let j of runningJobs.keys()) {
     if(j.id === jobId){
       stopped.push(j.stopThisInstance());
     }
  }

  res.json({success: {stopped}});

});
```

where

```
 const runningJobs = new Map<CDTChronBase,CDTChronBase>();
```

(CDTChronBase is a class)

the above works, but I'd like to simplify it if possible, something like this:

```
app.use('/stop_jobs', function (req, res, next) {
  const jobId = req.query && req.query.job_id;

  const stopped = runningJobs.keys().filter(j => {
     return j.id === jobId;
  })
  .map(v => {
     return j.stopThisInstance()
  });

  res.json({success: {stopped}});

});
```

but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get an Array instance of any of the methods on Map. Is there a way to use map/filter type methods on Map objects?

Comment: in your filter methode you need to return something to map

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
const stopped = Array.from(runningJobs.keys())
  .filter(j => j.id === jobId)
  .map(j => j.stopThisInstance());
```

Apart from that, you could also use [`filter` and `map` functions that work on iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718967/1048572) such as the `.keys()` of a Map.

Answer (score 1):

Since the key and value are same object, you can extract one of them and then covert it into an array.
If you convert map into array directly, it will be in `[[key, value],[key, value], ...]` structure. Then pick index 0:

```js
const stopped = Array.from(runningJobs)
  .map(job => job[0])
  .filter(key => key.id === jobId)
  .map(key => key.topThisInstance());
```

Comment: Key and value are of the same type, but they're not necessarily the same object. If they were, a `Set` should be used not a `Map`.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah. I got exactly same answer as yours when I try to test it :(