# Using a map function on a 'Map' to change values

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I can use a `Map` and then set values:

```
const a = new Map([["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]])
```

Now if I want to apply a function to all values in a functional way (without `for ... of` or `.forEach`), I thought I could have done something like this:

```
const b = a.map(([k, v]) => [k, doSomethingWith(v)]);
```

But there is no `map` function on a `Map`. Is there a built-in/elegant way to map a `Map`?

Comment: Use `Map#entries` then `.map` on them `a.entries().map(...)`

Comment: @ponury-kostek It won't work because `Map.entries()` return an Iterator (not Array); and Iterators haven't `.map` method...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no *elegant* way. You have to process the entries and then produce a new Map out of the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using map/filter behavior on Map instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49501690/1048572)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for getting entries and mapping new values and take this result for a new `Map`.

```
const b = new Map(Array.from(
    a, 
    ([k, v]) => [k, doSomethingWith(v)]
));
```

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant/concise way I am aware of is by converting the map to an array with the spread operator (`...`), applying `.map` to that array and then creating a Map from it again:

```
const a = new Map([["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]])
const b = new Map([...a].map(([k,v])=>[k, v.toUpperCase()]))
// b: Map(2) {"a" => "B", "c" => "D"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no builtin methods for this ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-collection-methods)!). The most elegant way currently is to use generators:

```
const b = new Map((function*() {
    for (const [k, v] of a)
        yield [k, doSomethingWith(v)];
})());
```

I would however recommend to write [helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718967/1048572) for this that work with arbitrary iterables:

```
function* mapValue(iterable, callback) {
    for (const [k, v] of a)
        yield [k, callback(v)];
}
const b = new Map(mapValue(a, doSomethingWith));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Symbol.iterator for changing or creating a new Map.

```js
function f (iterator) {
  for (let item of iterator1) {
    item[0] = 1;
    item[1] = 'hello world';
    console.log(item);
  }
}

var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('0', 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'bar');
var iterator1 = map1[Symbol.iterator]();

f(iterator1);
```

Comment: `for (let item of iterator1)` that should be `iterator`, no?

Comment: And the question was: '*in a functional way (without for ... of or .forEach)*'. This example uses `for...of`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like this:

```
let b = new Map(a)
b.forEach((value,key,myMap) => myMap.set(key, dosomething(value)))
```

or:

```
let b
(b = new Map(a)).forEach((value,key,myMap) => myMap.set(key, dosomething(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparison (& because these methods were a little ugly..), here's how to modify each value of a map using a traditional for .. of loop:

```
for (let entry of map.entries()) {
  let key = entry[0], value = entry[1];
  let newValue = value + ' '; // Modify however.
  map.set(key, newValue);
}
```