# How to purely work with the Map datatype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Title basically, I've just begun exploring es6 Map because of it's unique properties, and I'm a bit concerned about pure operations.

For example often remove properties from objects I work with using this:

```
function cloneOmit( obj, props ) {
  const keys = !Array.isArray(props)
    ? Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k !== props)
    : Object.keys(obj).filter(k => !props.includes(k));

  return keys.reduce(
    (clone, key) => {
      return { ...clone, [key]: obj[key] };
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

I rewrote this to work with Maps:

```
function cloneOmitMap( map, keys ) {
  const oldKeys = Array.from(map.keys());
  const newKeys = !Array.isArray(keys)
    ? oldKeys.filter(k => k !== keys)
    : oldKeys.filter(k => !keys.includes(k));

  return newKeys.reduce((newMap, key) => {
    return newMap.set(key, map.get(key));
  }, new Map());
}
```

Which is fine, but I'm not sure if it's performant or even the best way. I am attracted to Maps for their iteration capabilities (`Object.keys()` is cumbersome and ugly to constantly call), their adherence to order insertion, and especially their allowance of any value as a key but they do not seem nearly as conducive to pure operations as plain Objects are.

For instance, if I want to add a property to an object purely:

```
const object = { foo: 'bar' }
const newObject= { ...object, fooFoo: 'barBar' }
```

I'm wondering if there are some Map operations I'm not wary of that might help facilitate working with them purely, or maybe even a small utility library. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Checkout [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: ew no thank you. sorry, not sure if you have ever worked with immutable but it is a nightmare and way too cumbersome for what I'm going for

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it if I didn't strongly disagree with you.

Comment: I haven't worked with it in a long time so maybe it's been improved, but I remember it being a huge headache. I guess I'll keep it in mind, maybe it's worth another chance if you feel so strongly

Comment: You can make new Map basing on the old one (as well as Set from Set). Just make `var m = new Map()` make some values then `var n = new Map(m)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `Map`s by their iterator interfaces. Sure, creating lots of temporary immutable `Map`s won't be faster than using them mutably, but iterators should still be faster than doing everything with array conversions.

Using [these helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718967/1048572), your code could look like

```
function cloneOmit(map, keys) {
  const predicate = Array.isArray(keys)
    ? Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(keys))
    : k => k === keys

  return new Map(filter(map.entries(), ([key, value]) => !predicate(key)));
}
```